# Deserialise/Serialise JSON using Gson's RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory

Tags: android, recursion, deserialization, json-deserialization, gson

I am having the following kind of JSON coming from the server.

```
    {
    "templates": [
        {
          "right": [...],
          "left": [...],
          "available": true,
          "text": "some text here",
          "configuration": {
            "enabled": true,
            "trigger": {
                "triggerType": "MOVE",
                "eventName": "MOVING"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "right": [...],
          "left": [...],
          "available": true,
          "text": "some text here",
          "configuration": {
            "enabled": true,
            "trigger": {
              "triggerType": "DURATION",
              "duration": 300,
              "trigger": {
                "triggerType": "HALT",
                "description": "HAULTING"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    ]
    }
```

The JSON has an object "configuration" which may have recursive occurrence of element of "trigger". But this trigger type difference according to the configuration.

I think I have managed to create different class for different types of triggers with base class as "Trigger" as follows

```
public class Trigger{
private String triggerType;

    public String getTriggerType() {
        return triggerType;
    }

    public void setTriggerType(String triggerType) {
        this.triggerType = triggerType;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TiggerMove extends Trigger{

private String eventName;

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    } 
}
```

and

```
public class TiggerHault extends Trigger{

    private String description;

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        } 
    }
```

and

```
public class TiggerDuration extends Trigger{

private String duration;

private Tigger<T> trigger;

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    } 

    public String getTrigger() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setTrigger(Trigger trigger) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
    } 
}
```

I read few answers which mentioned to use [Gson's RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java). But I am not able to really able to use it as I see all the examples using it for first level elements and not inner elements.

How do I deserialise it using Android GSON?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a website like this [json to pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org). This site takes your json as an input and generates pojo classes that are specifically created to be used with gson. Gson will then deserialize your json without any issues.

Comment: I tried that but thats not helping as there are more then one occurrence of it in recursive way